# Comparing file lines to strings in python, and inconsistencies

Tags: python-3.x

Important things this code is supposed to in order of execution:

1.Open and read the file "Goods"

2.Assign a random line from file "Goods" to the dictionary "goods"

3.Go through an if block that will assign a random value to the dictionary "cost" if goods[x] equals the string it's being compared to.

4.Print "goods", and "cost"

5.Repeat steps 2-4, 2 more times.

```
from random import randint

print("You search for things to buy in the market, and find:")
f = open('Goods', 'r') #Opens file "Goods"
lines = f.readlines() #Loads all lines from "Goods"
goods = {1:"", 2:"", 3:""}
cost = {1:"", 2:"", 3:""}
x = 0
while x < 3:
    x += 1
    goods[x] = lines[randint(0, 41)].strip()

#Checks to see if goods[x] is equal to the string on the right, if it is, it assigns cost[x] to a random integer
    if goods[x] == "Lumber":
        cost[x] = randint(2, 3)
    elif goods[x] == "Rum":
        cost[x] == randint(3, 4)
    elif goods[x] == "Spices":
        cost[x] = randint(4, 5)
    elif goods[x] == "Fruit":
        cost[x] == randint(2, 4)
    elif goods[x] == "Opium":
        cost[x] == randint(1, 5)


    findings = '%s for %s gold.' %(goods[x], cost[x])
    print(findings)
```

The problem with this code is that the dictionary:"cost" does not get a value assigned from the if block when goods[x] equals: Rum, Fruit, or Opium.

Could someone please tell me what's going on here?

[The file "Goods"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJpYE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using two equal signs. `cost[x] == randint(3, 4)` you need to use just one. Hope this helps!